# How to put Json content type as HTML header

Tags: html, json

I have bash script. The results of this script is json type output (refreshing every second):

> {    "latitude": xxx,    "longitude": xxx,    "velocity": xxx
>   }

I want to put my JSON output into default index.html (main site of apache2 server), located in `/var/www/html`.

This operation is a first step to send data into my Client.
My question is how to include JSON file into html header to display my script output in web browser.

Thanks for any reply :)

Comment: It's very very unclear what the relationship between your script and Apache is. You haven't said what refreshes it. You haven't said where the "html index" comes from (are you talking about the output of `mod_autoindex`?).

Comment: It isn't clear why you've tagged this [tag:linux] (there's nothing specific to Linux in the question), nor [tag:rest] (as there's no sign of anything RESTful, but that could just be because you are being very vague), or [tag:mime] (because while you mention content types, you seem to be asking about putting JSON into an HTML document and not doing anything where the label of application/json matters).

Comment: you're right. I will edit my question immediately